# Glob matching, exclude all JS files

Tags: node.js, pattern-matching, glob, gulp

I'm a new user to gulp.js.  I'd like to move all of my non-javascript files to a build directory.  What I've got right now is this:

```
//Test copy
gulp.task('test-copy', function() {
    gulp.src(['myProject/src/**/*.!(js|map|src)'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('myProject/build'));
});


//Results for various files
myProject/css/style.css //Copied - GOOD
myProject/html/index.html //Copied - GOOD
myProject/js/foo.js //Not Copied - GOOD
myProject/js/bar.min.js //Copied - BAD!
myProject/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js //Copied - BAD!
myProject/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.map //Copied - BAD!
```

As you can see, it only matches after the first dot in the file path string, not the last one, as I'd like.  How can I modify the glob search string to behave as I'd like?

Comment: I haven't used gulp, but can you just add a $ to the end of the pattern being passed to gulp.src?

Comment: No, sadly this is not Regex, but rather [extglob](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) syntax.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Try this glob pattern:

```
myProject/src/**/!(*.js|*.map|*.src)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  For future stragglers, this caused a problem where my `.json` manifest file was also being excluded.  I modified the script like so, meaning it still copies `config.js` or `*.json` files:

`myProject/src/**/*(config.js|*.json|!(*.js|*.src|*map))`

Comment: This was extremely helpful for file matching with node's [grunt-ssh](https://github.com/israelroldan/grunt-ssh) and [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch).

Comment: This is annoying hard to come across even though it seems like such a common thing.

Comment: What if I want to match a file name with a specific prefix, say `foo`? Would it be `foo*!(*.js)`?