# node glob pattern include all js except in certain folders

Tags: node.js, node-glob

I have a project that looks like this

```
ls foo/
- file0.js
- a/file1.js
- b/file2.js
- c/file3.js
- d/file4.js
```

How do I write a [glob pattern](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) to **exclude the c & d folder** but get all other javascript files? I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557305/glob-matching-exclude-all-js-files) for an example, but cannot get anything to work.

I imagine the solution would look similar to this:

```
glob('+(**/*.js|!(c|d))', function(err, file) {
  return console.log(f);
});
```

I am wanting back

```
- file0.js
- a/file1.js
- b/file2.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an ignore option I glazed over in the readme:

```
glob('**/*.js', { ignore: '{c,d}/**' }, cb)
```

This will exclude both c + d folders from the match. More [here](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/180)

Answer (score 8):

For environment where there isn't a second parameter to set the exclude, we can achieve such an exception using the pattern demonstrated in the example bellow:

**Pattern**

```
/src/**/!(els)/*.scss
```

**structure**

```
/src/style/kit.scss
/src/style/els/some.scss
/src/style/els/two.scss
```

**result**

it will select only `/src/style/kit.scss`

We can use http://www.globtester.com or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob to test quickly online.

[image]

## update

If we are working with **Gulp task runner**. Or some other tools or classes that offers a second or multiple parameters for exclusion. Or just multiple globs selectors that support exclusion too. Then We can do as the example bellow for gulp show:

**for Gulp**

We pass an array instead of just a string (multiple globs selectors, one apply after another to add more files or to exclude)

```
src(['src/style/**/*.{scss,sass}', '!(src/style/els/**)'])
```

We can have multiple exclusions

```
watch(['src/style/**/*.{scss,sass}', '!(src/style/els/**)', '!(src/style/_somefileToExclude.scss)'])
```

In gulp you can use that, with any method that support an array as globs selectors. `src` and `watch` are what i used that for.

**Note:** If you want to exclude a folder and all it's sub folders we use `**` as above and not `**/*` which will not work. If you need some specific files types (extension) then you can use `**/*.scss` for example.