# Exclude files by filename with pattern gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to exclude files that have either ".fixtures.js", ".mocks.js", or ".tests.js" with gulp. For example I have:

```
client/js/app.js  
client/js/modules/services/myservice.js
client/js/modules/services/tests/myservice.tests.js
client/js/modules/directives/mydirective.js
client/js/modules/services/tests/mydirective.tests.js
client/js/modules/tests/global.mocks.js
client/js/modules/tests/global.fixtures.js
```

How can I exclude these all without manually doing:

```
gulp.src([
   'client/js/**/*.js',
   '!client/js/**/*.tests.js',
   '!client/js/**/*.fixtures.js',
   '!client/js/**/*.mocks.js',
])
.pipe(doSomething())
```

Comment: Could you please explain what's wrong with your solution? Since I use the same pattern for excluding files.

Comment: Is there something i can do like "!client/js/*.(tests||mocks||fixtures).js

Comment: Have you tried '!client/js/**/*.(tests|mocks|fixtures).js' as seen in the glob docs? https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Comment: When I do '!client/js/**/*.tests.js' it works, but if I do "!client/js/**/*.(tests|mocks|fixtures).js" it doesnt work. It keeps including those files

Comment: Maybe it has to be `"!client/js/**/(*.tests.js|*.mocks.js|*.fixtures.js)"` so you don't nest the globs. If we have to unnest the client/js/** as well, you're basically back to the original.

Comment: I seem to recall  'client/js/**/*.!(tests|mocks|fixtures).js' or you may need curly braces 'client/js/*.!{test|mocks|fixtures}.js'   but I can't find any examples just now.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557305/glob-matching-exclude-all-js-files.

    gulp.src([ 'client/js/**/!(*.tests|*.fixtures|*.mocks)*.js' ])

look like what you want.   Let me know if that fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially a duplicate of [exclude a set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557305/glob-matching-exclude-all-js-files).

```
gulp.src([ 'client/js/**/!(*.tests|*.fixtures|*.mocks)*.js' ])
```

look like what you want.