# Import all stylus files in the same folder

Tags: webpack, stylus

Currently i want to import all stylus file in `/src` folder, so i want put a stylus file

```
- src
| + index.styl
```

And put something into it like this:

```
@import '*./styl'
```

But you know, it will recursively import itself, too. So how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i've just found solution myself following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557305/glob-matching-exclude-all-js-files?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). I do something like this:

```
@import './!(index)*.styl'
```

Then, it works!