# Ignore certain files while packing a .tar.gz file in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, tar, packing

So I already have some code from the "targz" package that packs all the files inside of a directory. Now I have seen that you can somehow ignore files (not pack them) and I wanted to do it as well. I just can't figure out how I should write the ignore section. Here is my code:

```
targz.compress({
    src: "./" + this.sourcePath + "/",
    dest: "./" + this.targetPath + "/" + "result.tar.gz",
    tar: {
        entries: this.fileArray,
        ignore: function(name) {
            return path.extname(name) === '.pdf'
        }
    },
    gz: {
        level: 6,
        memLevel: 6,
    }
}, function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
    } else {
        resolve();
    }
});
```

Can somebody tell me how I need to write that section so it works? It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I would assume by not specifying them in the `src` section, at least nothing else is stated in the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/targz. Did you try using wildcards in there, like `*.php` to only include php files? If glob file matching is supported, this question might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557305/glob-matching-exclude-all-js-files

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with wildcards right now but still nothing. I more or less copy pasted the ignore section into my code, so I am confused as to why it wont work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the combination of `entries` and `ignore` is not working as you expect. If you include a file in `entries` it will be added to your archive, no matter what `ignore` does.

I don't think you need to specify the `entries` manually since you already specify a `src`. So removing the `entries` should do the trick.

Comment: Just tested it, thank you now it does filter out the pdf files. So I guess I have to edit the entries instead and cant work with ignore. Well, gotta do what you gotta do

Answer (score 0):

You got the `ignore` function which acts as a filter, for example from your code you are filtering all the files that have the `.pdf` extension.

You can rewrite this function to filter all the files and not your specific ones:

```
ignore: function filter(name) {
  const specificFilesToIgnore = ['some_specific.pdf', 'other_specific.pdf'];

  return path.extname(file) === '.pdf' && !specificFilesToIgnore.includes(name); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I think I did not explain myself properly. The code under the ignore fuction does not work, and I am trying to get it to work AT ALL first of. It will still pack '.pdf' files inside of my .tar.gz and I want to change that