# NodeJS&Glob: exclude arbitrary files with arbitrary filename extensions from glob selections in one string

Tags: node.js, glob

How can I exclude arbitrary file(s) with arbitrary filename  extension from glob
selection?

For example: we need all `.pug` and `.haml` files in `C:\Users\User1\projectname\src\markup`
except `index.pug` (but `index.haml` is O'K).

The glob

```
'C:\\Users\\User1\\projectname\\src\\markup\\!(index).+(pug|haml)'
```

excludes both `index.pug` and `index.haml` - this is not that we want, and also there is no enougnh flexibility.

Let's make clear:

1. In this question **we don't need to receive files** by glob - the target is just create single **glob** selection. So the solutions like `globby(['C:\\Users\\User1\\projectname\\src\\markup\\*.+(pug|haml)', '!C:\\Users\\User1\\projectname\\src\\markup\\index.pug']);` are
   not matches to this question.
2. If it's impossible - to exclude arbitrary file(s) with arbitrary extension(s) from glob - please say such as.

I tried

```
minimatch(
    'C:\\Users\\bokovgleb\\projectname\\src\\src\\index.pug',
    'C:\\Users\\bokovgleb\\projectname\\src\\src\\*(*.pug|!(index.pug))'
)
```

based on [comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23558259/4818123). It returns `true`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example: we need all .pug and .haml files in C:\Users\User1\projectname\src\markup except index.pug (but index.haml is O'K).

I came up with

```
/markup/!(*index){.pug,.haml,index.haml}
```

You can test it using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=%2Fmarkup%2F!(*index)%7B.pug%2C.haml%2Cindex.haml%7D&f=%2Fmarkup%2Fa.pug%2C%2Fmarkup%2Fb.pug%2C%2Fmarkup%2Fc.haml%2C%2Fmarkup%2Fd.haml%2C%2Fmarkup%2Findex.pug%2C%2Fmarkup%2Findex.haml)

Comment: I did not understand, why we need `*` in `(*index)`, but thanks to your I created my glob generator. And also thank you for globster!